# Accessing gvfs from command shell in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gvfs

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. I have some samba share mounted via Nautilus. I'd like to access the files from command shell. They used to appear under `$HOME/.gvfs` but not any more. Where have they gone to?

Answer (score 0):

GVFS mounts now appear under directory `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs`, where `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is typically set to `/run/user/<uid>`.

See [this answer to the question "What is this folder /run/user/1000?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/162911/15456) for more info on what `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is and why it exists.